# Yajra laravel datatable package not working properly in laravel 5.1 with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1, datatables-1.10, jenssegers-mongodb

I have installed yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle package for supporting serverside datatables in laravel 5.1 with mongodb 3.3 as database. I have connected laravel 5.1 with mongodb through jenssegers-mongodb package. It is connecting successfully , but datatable is not working properly.

js

```
$('#vendorDatatable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "ajax": baseUrl+'/vendors/data',
                "columns": [
                    {"data": 'branch', "name": 'branch'}
            ],
            });
```

Route

```
Route::get('vendors/data','VendorsController@getList');
```

VendorsController

```
public function getList(){
       $vendors = Vendors::select(['branch']);

        return Datatables::of($vendors)->make();

    }
```

Error while accessing ../vendors/data

```
FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 1309: Call to a member function compileSelect() on a non-object
```

Comment: Create an issue https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues here! I hope you can find quickly solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `->get()` to the query in controller

```
public function getList(){
   $vendors = Vendors::select(['branch'])->get();
   return Datatables::of($vendors)->make();
}
```

This is required to get the result data in proper format.